# Getting NuGet Package Vulnerability Information from an API

Tags: .net-core, nuget, dotnet-cli

We have been looking at ways that we can scan our code for NuGet packages that have vulnerabilities or are deprecated.

We have looked into using `dotnet list package --vulnerable` but this doesn't seem to be playing nicely with our Xamarin projects. It throws errors relating to missing project imports and we haven't found a way to get the tools to ignore the errors.

I think the issue is related to this: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/9035

Is it possible to replicate what the CLI tool is doing by calling NuGet APIs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had to check that for an old project of ours that was using packages.config (not supported by dotnet list) This is a powershell function that I have written and it helped in my case:

```
function Check-Package()
{
    param([string]$id ,[string]$version)
    $packages = Invoke-RestMethod "https://azuresearch-usnc.nuget.org/query?q=$id"
    $packageDetailsUrl = $packages.data | ? { $_.id -eq $id} | %{ $_.versions } |  ?{$_.version -eq $version } | %{ $_."@id"}
    if($packageDetailsUrl)
    {
        $packageDetails = Invoke-RestMethod $packageDetailsUrl
        
        $packageSuperDetails = Invoke-RestMethod $packageDetails.catalogEntry
        if($packageSuperDetails.vulnerabilities -or $packageSuperDetails.deprecation)
        {
            if($packageSuperDetails.deprecation)
            {
                $deprectaion = "is deprecated"
            }

            if($packageSuperDetails.vulnerabilities)
            {
                $vulnerability = "has vulnerabilities"
            }
            Write-Host $id $version $deprectaion $vulnerability
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host $id $version no longer listed on nuget.org
    }
}
```

I use it like that:

`nuget list -source .\packages\ | %{Check-Package -id $_.Split(" ")[0] -version $_.Split(" ")[1]`